# Combining data and header to create dta

Tags: python, stata

I have tab-delimited txt data without header

```
1990    1   3
1991    0   2
1990    1   1
```

And I have headers information like this.

```
 VARIABLE LABELS         
    C1 'Year'
    C2 'Sex'
    C3 'Region'
```

How can I combine them (put the header to tab-delimited txt) to create a Stata dta file?

A roundabout way to do is maybe to combine the two files into txt using python, and then converting it to dta. How can this work?

Answer (score 3):

I am puzzled by the interest in roundabout ways to do this. A direct way to do this in Stata is

```
import delimited Year Sex Region using mydata.txt 
save mydata
```

Your real problem could be more complicated, but if so, you will need to give a better explanation. In particular,

1. You say nothing about how the variable labels are held, whether they are on a sheet of paper, in your head, or in some other file. For a more extensive list it may be best to create a `.do` file with the commands to `label` each variable.
2. In your example the variable labels could all be variable names, so there is no need to use the uninformative names you mention. Many variable labels are not so suited.

Comment: @Nick_Cox Thank you very much. My interest in roundabout way was due to my lack of Stata knowledge. Thank you!